# MongoDB - upsert involving lists

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm a MongoDB newbie and wanted to ask how to write an update command involving upsert and list.

Basically I want to accomplish something like this:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("4c28f62cbf8544c60506f11d"),
"some_other_data":"goes here",
"trips": [
    {"name": "2010-05-10",
     "loc": [{"lat":21.321231, "lng": 16.8783234, "updated_at": "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:35"}, 
        {"lat":21.321231, "lng": 16.8783234, "updated_at": "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:24"}]
    },
    {"name": "2010-05-08",
     "loc": [{"lat":21.324239, "lng": 16.8735234, "updated_at": "Mon May 8 2010 11:18:05"},
        {"lat":21.311234, "lng": 16.8743271, "updated_at": "Mon May 8 2010 11:17:55"}, 
        {"lat":21.321238, "lng": 16.8782219, "updated_at": "Mon May 8 2010 11:17:45"}]
    }
]}
```

Note that:

- You supply a trip name and the
  current location
- If the trip does not exist already, it
  needs to be created
- trips.name should be unique so that
  if it exists, you append to the
  location array

This is the query I wrote combining the positional operator with $push.

```
    db.mycollection.update({"application_id": "MyTestApp", 
                            "trips.name": "2010-05-10"},
                           {$push: {'trips.$.loc': {"lat":11, "lng":11} }}, 
                           true);
```

But this results in data like this:

```
> db.mycollection.find({"application_id":"MyTestApp"})          
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c29044ebf8544c60506f11f"), 
"application_id" : "MyTestApp", 
"trips" : { "$" : { "loc" : [ { "lat" : 11, "lng" : 11 } ] }, 
"name" : "2010-05-10" } 
}
```

You can see that

- "trips" is not an array
- it took "$" literally and created a
  key with that (doh!)

So far I've been pretty happy with MongoDB, but there's definitely a steep learning curve with writing complicated queries.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, 
Amie

Comment: check my answer below again - I edited it to include what I believe to be the solution (or at least something that should get you very close)

Comment: see this [SO Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994552/mongodb-update-documents-in-an-array/17995495#17995495).

something similar to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mix the positional operator ("$") and an upsert; the "$" will be treated as a field name during the insert. You can't do this for new documents, only existing one.

I suggested a structure more like this:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("4c28f62cbf8544c60506f11d"),
"some_other_data":"goes here",
"trips": { 
    "2010-05-10":
       [{"lat":21.321231, "lng": 16.8783234, "updated_at": "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:35"}, 
        {"lat":21.321231, "lng": 16.8783234, "updated_at": "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:24"}],
    "2010-05-08": 
       [{"lat":21.324239, "lng": 16.8735234, "updated_at": "Mon May 8 2010 11:18:05"},
        {"lat":21.311234, "lng": 16.8743271, "updated_at": "Mon May 8 2010 11:17:55"}, 
        {"lat":21.321238, "lng": 16.8782219, "updated_at": "Mon May 8 2010 11:17:45"}]
    }
}
```

Then you can issue an update like this:

```
db.mycollection.update({application_id: "MyTestApp", "trips.2010-05-10":{$exists:true}},
                       {$push: {"trips.2010-05-10": {lat:11, lng:11} }}, 
                       true);
```

results in this being inserted.

```
> db.mycollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c2931d17b210000000045f0"), 
    "application_id" : "MyTestApp", 
    "trips" : { "2010-05-10" : [ { "lat" : 11, "lng" : 11 } ] } }
```

and running it again give you this:

```
> db.mycollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c2932db7b210000000045f2"), 
    "application_id" : "MyTestApp", 
    "trips" : { "2010-05-10" : 
        [ { "lat" : 11, "lng" : 11 }, 
          { "lat" : 11, "lng" : 11 } ] } }
```

Comment: This is very close to what I tried to achieve. Thanks @Scott Hernandez. With this schema, is it possible to retrieve a list of keys in the "trips"? ("2010-050-10", etc) db.mycollection.find({"application_id":"MytestApp"}, {"trips":true}) returns the entire "trips" hash.

Comment: I ended up going with this method. Thanks for the solution Scott!

Comment: The problem there is that you can't query for something within a trip, like find documents with a trip at lat 21.321231 (as mongo (today) has no way to 'wild-card' part of the path to the field).

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED TO INCLUDE CORRECT SOLUTION**

This is exactly the problem I hit learning Mongo - you're looking for the `$addToSet` operator ([see docs here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24addToSet)) that's used with the `update` command, in conjunction with the `$` positional operator you were using.

> $addToSet
>
> { $addToSet : { field : value } }
>
> Adds value to the array only if its not in the array already.

The query thus becomes (db.stack is the collection I used for testing purposes), sample run to follow:

```
db.stack.update({ "trips.name":"2010-05-10" }, 
                { $addToSet: { "trips.$.loc":{"lat":11, "lng":12} } }
               );
```

TEST RUN (with some abbreviations for space of the elements that aren't important):

```
#### YOUR ITEM IN THE DB
> db.stack.find({"trips.name":"2010-05-10"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c28f62cbf8544c60506f11d"), "some_other_data" : "goes here", 
    "trips" : [
    { "name" : "2010-05-10",
        "loc" : [ {
                "lat" : 21.321231,
                "lng" : 16.8783234,
                "updated_at" : "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:35"
            }, { "lat" : 21.321231,
                "lng" : 16.8783234,
                "updated_at" : "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:24"
            } ] },
    { "name" : "2010-05-08",
        "loc" : [ ... ]
    } ] }
#### SUCCESSFULLY ADDS ITEM TO PROPER ARRAY
> db.stack.update({"trips.name":"2010-05-10"}, {$addToSet: {"trips.$.loc":{"lat":11, "lng":11}}});
> db.stack.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c28f62cbf8544c60506f11d"), "some_other_data" : "goes here",
    "trips" : [
        { "loc" : [
                { "lat" : 21.321231,
                    "lng" : 16.8783234,
                    "updated_at" : "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:35"
                }, { "lat" : 21.321231,
                    "lng" : 16.8783234,
                    "updated_at" : "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:24"
                }, { "lat" : 11,
                    "lng" : 11
                }
            ], "name" : "2010-05-10"
        },
        { "name" : "2010-05-08",
            "loc" : [ ...  ]
        } ] }
#### ON REPEAT RUN DOESN'T ADD NEW ELEMENT
> db.stack.update({"trips.name":"2010-05-10"}, {$addToSet: {"trips.$.loc":{"lat":11, "lng":11}}});
> db.stack.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c28f62cbf8544c60506f11d"), "some_other_data" : "goes here",
    "trips" : [ {
            "loc" : [
                { "lat" : 21.321231,
                    "lng" : 16.8783234,
                    "updated_at" : "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:35"
                }, { "lat" : 21.321231,
                    "lng" : 16.8783234,
                    "updated_at" : "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:24"
                }, { "lat" : 11,
                    "lng" : 11
                }
            ], "name" : "2010-05-10"
        },
        { "name" : "2010-05-08",
            "loc" : [ ...  ]
        } ] }
#### BUT WILL CORRECTLY ADD ANOTHER ELEMENT TO THE SAME ARRAY IF IT'S NOT PRESENT
> db.stack.update({"trips.name":"2010-05-10"}, {$addToSet: {"trips.$.loc":{"lat":11, "lng":12}}});
> db.stack.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4c28f62cbf8544c60506f11d"), "some_other_data" : "goes here",
    "trips" : [
        { "loc" : [
                { "lat" : 21.321231,
                    "lng" : 16.8783234,
                    "updated_at" : "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:35"
                }, { "lat" : 21.321231,
                    "lng" : 16.8783234,
                    "updated_at" : "Mon May 10 2010 15:24:24"
                }, { "lat" : 11,
                    "lng" : 11
                }, { "lat" : 11,
                    "lng" : 12
                }
            ], "name" : "2010-05-10"
        },
        { "name" : "2010-05-08",
            "loc" : [ ... ]
    } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Anthony Morelli. I tried $addToSet and had to pass in upsert=true to insert a trip for the first time. When I changed the trip name to something else, this actually creates a new document instead of using the current doc. How can we specify that "trips" is an array?

Comment: What query did you run specifically? $addToSet only works with arrays, so I don't think that specification is the problem.

Comment: I ran your query exactly, and it didn't create a doc, so I passed in upsert=true. After it creates the first doc, when it ran for the second time, it created a second doc instead of appending it to the previous one..

Comment: I believe I fixed it - see edit. Basically, I forgot the positional operator which is necessary to specify which item in the trips array should be updated. The new query is `db.stack.update({"trips.name":"2010-05-10"}, {$addToSet: {"trips.$.loc":{"lat":11, "lng":12}}});` - I tested it with your existing schema and it works fine.

Comment: Is it correct to say that this only works if the document already exists? (As Scott pointed out, we can't use "$" and an upsert together) But I can see this can be useful in some cases. Thanks for the comprehensive update!

Comment: Unfortunately, it would only work on a preexisting doc. But you could write a query to test and then either insert or update that would process just about as quickly. A find operation would get you the ObjectID (if existing), so the find and then update would be optimized as looking up a specific ObjectID would add a negligible overhead. In the event that the document didn't exist, be able to insert it (again with minimal added overhead). Is that what you're looking for?