# MongoDB - update documents in an array

Tags: mongodb

> **UPDATE:** I suggest to read my accepted answer, which gives you different approach on this problem.

I have following collection.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51fa56408e843042c0c24e3d"),
        "uniqDates" : [
                ISODate("2013-07-30T18:30:00Z"),
                ISODate("2013-07-31T18:30:00Z")
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51fa5648c424ea3e37199502"),
        "events" : [
                {
                        "eid" : 1,
                        "title" : "Event 1",
                        "start" : ISODate("2013-08-04T18:30:00Z")
                },
                {
                        "eid" : 2,
                        "title" : "Event 2",
                        "start" : ISODate("2013-08-08T18:30:00Z")
                }
        ]
}
```

I want to update a document in "events" array if it exists (i want to check it by eid), if it doesn't exists i want to insert that document.

currently i am doing this with two queries.

```
db.col.update({events: {$exists: 1}}, {$pull: {"events": {"eid": 2}}});
```

and

```
db.schedule.update({events: {$exists: 1}}, {$addToSet: 
{"events": {"eid": 2, "title": "Event 4", "start": new Date(2013, 08, 02)}}});
```

Is there a way to do this with single query? Something with upsert operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135927/mongodb-upsert-involving-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE**

It is pretty obvious mindset to have collection like above to group documents.
But having documents in array will result in some other problems. You
have to suffer with [Array Update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) operators to update each
document. Instead, i restructured my collection as shown below. Also,
see this [google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/ELrOEuH1iV4). As "idbentley" specified there
is a possibility to exceed document size limit (16 MB) which will
lead to data fragmentation. So be conscious while you model your data.*

***Original Answer***

It seems like it is not possible to achieve upsert operation in document array. So changed my schema design like below.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51fa619a8e843042c0c24e46"),
        "uniqDates" : [
                ISODate("2013-07-30T18:30:00Z"),
                ISODate("2013-07-31T18:30:00Z")
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51fa61b38e843042c0c24e47"),
        "eid" : 1,
        "title" : "Event 1",
        "start" : ISODate("2013-08-04T18:30:00Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51fa61b38e843042c0c24e48"),
        "eid" : 2,
        "title" : "Event 2",
        "start" : ISODate("2013-08-08T18:30:00Z")
}
```

To find events:

```
db.schedule.find({"eid": {$exists: 1}});
```

To find unique date:

```
db.schedule.find({"uniqDates": {$exists: 1}});
```

To achieve 'upsert' operation:

```
db.schedule.update({"eid": 3}, {"eid": 3, "title": "Event 3", 
                                "start": new Date(2013, 05, 06)}, true);
```

This seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll still need to do this with two queries.  But, using a [$ query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#op._S_) to `update`, you can keep it to one query in the case where the EID already exists.

```
db.col.update({"events.eid": 2}}, {$set: {"events.$.title: "Event 4", "events.$.start": new Date(2013, 08, 02}})
```

If the return value from that indicates that no records were found, then you can insert it instead.